# Php for / switch

Tags: php

Lo que hace la función es mostrar un aviso en la pantalla con el nombre de usuario y un enlace a su perfil, después de unos segundos se cierra el aviso.

Lo que debería hacer el switch es mostrar la información del usuario 1 y al terminar la animación mostrar la información del usuario 2 pero lo que hace en realidad es mostrar la información del primer usuario y al terminar la animación volver a mostrar la información del primero en lugar del segundo.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
function notificacion($connection, $usuario_id){
    $usuario_sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario_id = '$usuario_id'";
    $usuario_resultado = mysqli_query($connection, $usuario_sql);

    if ($usuario = $usuario_resultado->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '
        <a href="../usuario.php?id=' . $usuario['usuario_id'] . '">
        <div id="notificacion2" title="Ver usuario">

        <span class="usuario"><i class="fa fa-user ' . $usuario['usuario_nombre'] . '"></i></span>
        </div><!-- notificacion --></a>

        <script>
        $("#notificacion2").delay(1000).animate({width: "toggle"}).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
        </script>';
    }
}


for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++){

switch ($i){

    case 1:
    // 1
        notificacion($connection, 1);
        break;

    case 2:
    // 2
        notificacion($connection, 2);
        break;      
}
}
```

Comment: He probado ++$i y obtengo el mismo resultado.

Comment: con if/else if en lugar de switch/case me da el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1):

El error es que está pensando que cuando imprime un `script` con código de animación con un intervalo de retraso o cosas así que pertenecen al lado del cliente `echo '<script></script>'`, se detendrá o se parará la ejecución del  `script` `PHP` , lo cuál no sucede así. la ejecución del `script` se ejecuta indistintamente de estas operaciones.

Lo cuál no tendrá el resultado que desea, podría emplear `sleep` pero tampoco es aconsejable , en su lugar podría hacer una llamada `Ajax` y retorne todos los usuarios , o una llamad por `id` , y ya con esos datos que retorne la llamada, en el cliente podrá realizar la animación que requiera.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy acostumbrado al modo procedimental, pero creo que estas dos líneas te están dando problemas:

```
$usuario_resultado = mysqli_query($connection, $usuario_sql);

    if ($usuario = $usuario_resultado->fetch_assoc()){
```

Intenta de esta manera, y de paso usamos en todo el modo orientado a objetos. En tu código estás mezclando los dos estilos y eso no es recomendable, porque estarás escribiendo programas confusos para ti y para los demás.

```
function notificacion($connection, $usuario_id){
    $usuario_sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario_id = '$usuario_id'";

    if ($usuario_resultado = $connection->query($usuario_sql)) {
        /* obtener un array asociativo */
        while ($usuario = $usuario_resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '
            <a href="../usuario.php?id=' . $usuario['usuario_id'] . '">
            <div id="notificacion2" title="Ver usuario">

            <span class="usuario"><i class="fa fa-user ' . $usuario['usuario_nombre'] . '"></i></span>
            </div><!-- notificacion --></a>

            <script>
            $("#notificacion2").delay(1000).animate({width: "toggle"}).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
            </script>';

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me da el mismo resultado

Comment: @Kakotas7  La lógica de la consulta funciona, pero no estás imprimiendo nada fuera del enlace. Yo he puesto algo fuera y me funciona. Aunque es extraña la forma de tu `anchortag`. No sé por qué tienes un `div` y un `span` dentro de él. Si pones el `echo` de esta manera a mi me funciona, pero eso debería ser revisado...

Comment: `$strHTML= '<a href="../usuario.php?id=' . $usuario['usuario_id'] . '">'.$usuario['usuario_nombre']. 
          '<div id="notificacion2" title="Ver usuario">'.
          '<span class="usuario"><i class="fa fa-user ' . $usuario['usuario_nombre'] . '"></i></span>'.
          '</div><!-- notificacion --></a>'.
    '<script>'.
    ' $("#notificacion2").delay(1000).animate({width: "toggle"}).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);'.
    '</script>';
echo $strHTML;`

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo resultado, el anchortag es raro porque he eliminado la mayoría de cosas que había dentro para facilitar la lectura. Igual estoy haciendo algo mal pero lo que hace tu código es imprimir el resultado en pantalla directamente y eso ya lo hacía antes. El problema lo tengo con el delay de la animación que siempre muestra el mismo resultado aunque en un echo normal muestre ambos.